# Foursquare API response undesired in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, foursquare

I am working on fixing the GET request using Foursquare's search venue. I'm currently getting back the HTTP URL, which somehow doesn't fetch the desirable result like it's should be identical to the URL I used by the Apigee web console. (I used Alamofire's library for more compact use of the HTTP request work. Also, I'm going for useless authentication right for now to focus on working on fetching the JSON data).

Below is the snippet (part of the function) given.

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    .....
    //do HTTP GET to get the user's current venue 
    let para2 : Parameters = [
        "v": AutoCheckInVC.DATE_VERIFIED,
        "ll": ll,
        "intent": "browse", 
        "radius": "100000", 
        "client_id": AutoCheckInVC.CLIENT_ID,
        "client_secret" : AutoCheckInVC.CLIENT_SECRET,
    ]

    Alamofire.request("https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search", parameters: para2).responseJSON{ response in
        print("Response: \(String(describing: response.response))") //HTTP encoded
        if let JSON = response.result.value {
            print("JSON: \(JSON)")
        }
```

The URL response from the code is `https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?client_id=....&client_secret=....&intent=browse&ll=-71.1%2C42.37&radius=100000&v=20161016`, which is not like the one to be expected on **apigee.com/console/** as `https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?client_id=....&client_secret=....&intent=browse&ll=-71.1%2C42.37&radius=100000&v=20161016`.

So how do I fix the format order of incorrect URL response to be similar to the correct one?

Comment: Is it because I forgot to add the query parameter "intent" as _intent=checkin_ to my HTTP GET request? Cuz I'm using this console website _https://apigee.com/console_, and it mentioned about this query.

Comment: I just updated my question more specifically

Comment: Can you share what the error response you're getting is? The API call you showed is working for me